# How do I destructure a range in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to use destructuring in ruby to extract the end and beginning from a range?

```
module PriceHelper
  def price_range_human( range )
    "$%s to $%s" % [range.begin, range.end].map(:number_to_currency)
  end
end
```

I know that I can use array coercion as a really bad hack:

```
first, *center, last = *rng
"$%s to $%s" % [first, last].map(:number_to_currency)
```

But is there a syntactical way to get `begin` and `end` without actually manually creating an array?

```
min, max = (1..10)
```

Would have been awesome.

Comment: You need to either state that you are only concerned about two-dot ranges or clarify whether you want `max` or `last`, which you seem to use interchangeability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>No,</strike> Until I am proven incorrect by Cary Swoveland, Weekly World News or another tabloid, I'll continue believing without any evidence that the answer is "no"; but it's easy enough to make.

```
module RangeWithBounds
  refine Range do
    def bounds
      [self.begin, self.end]
    end
  end
end

module Test
  using RangeWithBounds
  r = (1..10)
  b, e = *r.bounds
  puts "#{b}..#{e}"
end
```

Then again, I'd just write `"#{r.begin.number_to_currency}..#{r.end.number_to_currency}"` in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't `*r`coerce the range into an array?

Comment: @max: No, `*r.bounds` is `*(r.bounds)`, not `(*r).bounds`. Remember that `*` is not an operator, but a syntactic construct in assignment lvalue, assignment rvalue, argument list (both definition and call) and array literal. It does not even have priority, because it can't be evaluated "inside" an expression.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that makes more sense. I had never considered that you can't do `array.*` as you can with operators.

Comment: I had not considered excluding ranges either which would have made `a, b = (1...10)` ambiguous.

Comment: You can replace `[self.begin, self.end]` with `[first, last]`, but not with `[begin, end]`, `[begin, last]` or `[first, end]`, as `begin` and `end` are reserved words. @max, perhaps you were thinking of `[*1..4]
 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - no - casting to an array is exactly what I was trying to avoid. I was just wondering if ruby had a syntax to get the bounds of a range - its more of a theoretical than practical question.

Comment: @max, ah, I was addressing your first comment above, having missed the fact that it's your question.

Comment: Amadan, you haven't shown evidence for "No" in your first sentence. That is the question, after all. Also, `bounds` returns an array. Isn't that a violation?

Comment: It is not a coercion of the Range object. It is a newly constructed array of two elements. You can't do multiple return in Ruby without an arrays. As for your first complaint... what kind of evidence do you expect for a negative existential? Positive claims are proven, negative claims are *dis*proven. If you want formal proof here, it's on you to prove me wrong.

Comment: "No" constitutes an assertion. We should expect a proof or at least arguments to support assertions. If you cannot provide that, you should make it clear that you are giving an opinion or be mute on that point.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It is my opinion that no such syntax exists. It is also my opinion that leprechauns aren't real. I can't prove either. However, if you give me a counterexample, I will delete this answer as inaccurate, and start following rainbows.

Comment: I don't dispute that (not even the reference to [leprechauns](http://weeklyworldnews.com/headlines/28208/scientists-capture-leprechaun/)). I just think you should say "It is my opinion.." rather than a barren "No", as readers may take that as a fact.

Comment: In my earlier comment "You can replace..." I overlooked the fact that `max` and `last` are not equivalent, as Amadan pointed out in a comment on @theTinMan's answer. My comment only applies to two-dot hashes.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `minmax` to destructure ranges:

```
min, max = (1..10).minmax
min # => 1
max # => 10
```

If you are using Ruby before 2.7, avoid using this on large ranges.

Comment: Be aware that this returns the range's minimum and maximum value, not the begin and end of the range.

Comment: Also be aware that this doesn't handle infinite ranges well. `(-Float::INFINITY..0).minmax` raises `TypeError` and `(0..Float::INFINITY).minmax` never returns a value.

Comment: I.e., `minmax` iterates through the range, whereas `[range.min, range.max]` doesn't iterate the range and works fine with infinite ranges. So avoid `minmax` if your range has a huge (or infinite) number of items.

Comment: In Ruby 2.7, minmax does not iterate through the Range anymore and works fine with infinite ranges  https://rubyreferences.github.io/rubychanges//2.7.html#minmax-implementation-change

Answer (score 4):

The beginning and end? I'd use:

```
foo = 1..2
foo.min # => 1
foo.max # => 2
```

Trying to use destructuring for a range is a bad idea. Imagine the sizes of the array that could be generated then thrown away, wasting CPU time and memory. It's actually a great way to DOS your own code if your range ends with `Float::INFINITY`.

---

> `end` is not the same as `max`: in 1...10, `end` is 10, but `max` is 9

That's because `start_val ... end_val` is equivalent to `start_val .. (end_val - 1)`:

```
start_value = 1
end_value = 2

foo = start_value...end_value
foo.end # => 2
foo.max # => 1

foo = start_value..(end_value - 1)
foo.end # => 1
foo.max # => 1
```

`max` reflects the reality of the values actually used by Ruby when iterating over the range or testing for inclusion in the range.

In my opinion, `end` should reflect the actual maximum value that will be considered inside the range, not the value used at the end of the definition of the range, but I doubt that'll change otherwise it'd affect existing code.

`...` is more confusing and leads to increased maintenance problems so its use is not recommended.

Comment: `Range#min` and `max` are not the same as `end` and `begin`.  `max` actually converts the array to a range and gets the last element afaik.

Comment: Its basically because `#max` can be called as `max(n) {| a,b | block } → obj`.

Comment: `min` and `max` return the start and end of the range. There's nothing in the documentation saying it's converted to an array. If it was, converting `1..Float::INFINITY` when using `max` would never return. They're basically the same as `begin` and `end` except they allow the use of a block. `begin` and `end` should be faster though, from looking at the source.

Comment: Try calling `(1..Float::INFINITY).max` with a block.

Comment: Although calling it without a block does not cause your program to blow up anymore like in 1.9.3

Comment: @theTinMan: Note that `#end` is not the same as `#max`: in `1...10`, `#end` is `10`, but `#max` is `9`. In `10..1`, `#end` is `1`, but `#max` is `nil`. You should pick according to your use case whether you want `#begin` and `#end` (and  `#exclude_end?`), or `#min` and `#max`.

Comment: Another special case: `(1...2.5).max` raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Amadan's answer is fine. you just need to remove the splat (*) when using it since it is not needed

eg,

```
> "%s to %s" % (1..3).bounds.map{|x| number_to_currency(x)}
=> "$1.00 to $3.00"
```